# Removing duplicate data doesn't seem to be actually removing dups?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to preprocess some data and am running this command:

```
df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['ticker','periodDate'], keep='first')]
```

but when I look for dups, they are still there:

```
dups = df[df.duplicated(subset=['ticker','periodDate'], keep=False)]
print (dups[dups['ticker'] == 'cofe.us'])

         ticker  periodDate  ... exchangeRateChanges cashAndCashEquivalentsChanges
348     cofe.us        2017  ...                 0.0                           0.0
300109  cofe.us        2018  ...                 0.0                           0.0
300110  cofe.us        2018  ...                 0.0                           0.0
300111  cofe.us        2017  ...                 0.0                           0.0
300112  cofe.us        2017  ...                 0.0                           0.0
300113  cofe.us        2017  ...                 0.0                           0.0
300114  cofe.us        2017  ...                 0.0                           0.0
300115  cofe.us        2016  ...                 0.0                           0.0
300116  cofe.us        2016  ...                 0.0                           0.0
300117  cofe.us        2016  ...                 NaN                           NaN
300118  cofe.us        2016  ...                 NaN                           NaN
```

My goal is simply to keep the first match for ticker and periodDate then disregard the others.

Comment: Simple bug. You actually want to `df[~df.duplicated(subset=[....], keep='first')]`. Otherwise you're just filtering all duplicated values. You forgot the `~` in front of duplicated

Comment: @rafaelc agghhh I didn't even what ~ does. that's interesting. Thank you - can you post that as a answer and I'll accept

Comment: Sounds good. Done.

Comment: @rafaelc thank you so much. ~ option is so cool..love this site, always learning new things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`duplicated` returns the duplicated rows. By doing `df[df.duplicated(....)]`, you keep only the duplicated rows, instead of filtering them out.

Use `~` to get the non-dupes:

```
df[~df.duplicated(subset=[....], keep='first')]
```